# How do I get an event in Raphael's paper coordinates

Tags: raphael

I would like to get the coordinates of a mouse event in Raphael's paper coordinates.  I would like those to be accurate even when I have used setViewBox.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/CEnBN/

The following creates a 10x10 green box and then zooms way in - with the center of that box at the view's origin.

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

var rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
rect.attr('fill', 'green');

rect.mousedown(function (event, a, b) {
    $('#here').text([a, b]);
    console.log(event);
});

paper.setViewBox(5, 5, 10, 10);
```

I would like to receive click coordinates that reflect their position in the box.  ie. they should range from ([5-10], [5-10]).

---

Note: much later, and I have migrated to D3.js - which has generally made me a lot happier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: simplified by using clientX/Y of the mouse event - remove need to get element offset

Here is what I came up with. Basically, correct the mouse position to be relative to the paper by using the client rect of the paper and clientX/Y of the mouse event. Then compare the corrected positions to the client rect's width/height, then factor the results by original paper dimensions:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

var rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
rect.attr('fill', 'green');

rect.mousedown(function (event, a, b) {
    // get bounding rect of the paper
    var bnds = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

    // adjust mouse x/y
    var mx = event.clientX - bnds.left;
    var my = event.clientY - bnds.top;

    // divide x/y by the bounding w/h to get location %s and apply factor by actual paper w/h
    var fx = mx/bnds.width * rect.attrs.width
    var fy = my/bnds.height * rect.attrs.height

    // cleanup output
    fx = Number(fx).toPrecision(3);
    fy = Number(fy).toPrecision(3);

    $('#here').text('x: ' + fx + ', y: ' + fy);
});

paper.setViewBox(5, 5, 10, 10);
```

An updated fiddle link is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/CEnBN/3/

more compact version of mouse down func:

```
rect.mousedown(function (event, a, b) {
    var bnds = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var fx = (event.clientX - bnds.left)/bnds.width * rect.attrs.width
    var fy = (event.clientY - bnds.top)/bnds.height * rect.attrs.height

    $('#here').text('x: ' + fx + ', y: ' + fy);
});
```

Comment: That's it.  I wish it were cleaner - not your fault.

Answer (score 0):

You need to offset the result, something like this:

```
var posx, posy;

var paper = Raphael("canvas", 320, 200);

var rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
rect.attr('fill', 'green');

rect.mousedown(function (e, a, b) {
    posx = e.pageX - $(document).scrollLeft() - $('#canvas').offset().left;
    posy = e.pageY - $(document).scrollTop() - $('#canvas').offset().top;
    $('#here').text([posx, posy]);
    console.log(e);
});

paper.setViewBox(5, 5, 10, 10);
```

I added an element for Raphaeljs to target, have a look at [this update to your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CEnBN/1/)

Comment: That's a minor improvement, I guess - but it certainly does not account for the scaling or for the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by gthmb is very good, but missing a detail - the position of the rectangle on the paper. This version is only working, if the rectangle is at position (0,0). To support also the situation where it is translated, add the position of the rectangle to the result:

```
function mouseEvent_handler(e) {
    var bnds = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var bbox = this.getBBox();
    var fx = (event.clientX - bnds.left)/bnds.width * rect.attrs.width + bbox.x;
    var fy = (event.clientY - bnds.top)/bnds.height * rect.attrs.height + bbox.y;

    $('#here').text('x: ' + fx + ', y: ' + fy);
}
```

Here the modified version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zJu8b/1/